# How to put multiple middlewares on the way of a route in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Here is my code:

```
Route::post('agent_purchase_order/register', 'agent_purchase_orderController@register')
->name('agent_purchase_order_register_do')
->middleware('accessibility')
->middleware('cors');
```

Apparently it doesn't work. Noted that those middlewares works when I use them separately. Any idea how can I handle that?

Comment: This is easily searchable, have you done any effort? Its right there in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple middlewares can be added within a single `middleware()` function as:

```
Route::post('agent_purchase_order/register', 'agent_purchase_orderController@register')
        ->name('agent_purchase_order_register_do')
        ->middleware('accessibility', 'cors');
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [laravel official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware)
You may also assign multiple middleware to the route:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    //
})->middleware('first', 'second');
```

When u use grouping in your route, just pass array to middleware

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['first','second']], function () {
    Route::post('agent_purchase_order/register', 'agent_purchase_orderController@register')
        ->name('agent_purchase_order_register_do'); 
});
```

Comment: And in your second version how can I write another parameters like `->name('agent_purchase_order_register_do')` ?

Comment: Yes u can. Just put Route code inside function() {}. I edited code above. Check this

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['accessibility','cors'], function () {
    Route::post('agent_purchase_order/register', 'agent_purchase_orderController@register')
        ->name('agent_purchase_order_register_do'); 
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

hope, this way would help, would you please check and apply.

`Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['accessibility', 'cors']]);`